# texttospeech cannot read in French in the xamarin android application

Tags: xamarin

Hello I am creating an application in xamarin which allows the user to listen to the sounds of the texts in English and in French, but I found that in English it works but in French no sound of the texts here are my codes :

public class ActivityA : AppCompatActivity,TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
{

```
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private TextToSpeech tts1;
  
 

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

                     tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        tts1 = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
     }
    private void TxtProv3b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //In french
    tts1.Speak("A méchant ouvrier, point de bons outils", QueueMode.Flush, null);

    }

       private void TxtProv1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // In english
        tts.Speak("A bad excuse is better than none", QueueMode.Flush, null);
       
    }
       public void OnInit([GeneratedEnum] OperationResult status)
      {
        if (status == OperationResult.Success)
        {
            tts.SetLanguage(Locale.Us);
            tts1.SetLanguage(Locale.French);
          

           
        }
     }
```

}
i need help please

Answer (score 0):

> Text to speech is not quite the reverse of speech to text and relies
> on two key components; a text-to-speech engine being installed on the
> device and a language being installed.

So you could check if French voice data was download.You could use
`Java.Util.Locale.GetAvailableLocales().ToList();` to test against the installed languages.

The more information you could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/speech#text-to-speech).